# Auto export constants in submodule

Tags: rust, namespaces, documentation

## The problem

I have a module (that defines a trait) with a bunch of submodule that will be added, modified or removed as the program evolves. Each module defines a bunch of constants, basically commands that the module accepts, which I'd like to regroup in documentation, while still keeping the actual definition of each submodule constants in the submodule's file.

## What I tried

One simple way to do that is to re-export all the constants, and use wildcards to avoid listing every single constant, as well as modules to only re-export what I need, without poluting the Base namespace :

```rust
// a.rs

pub(super) mod Cmds {
    /// Some doc
    pub const CMD_A1: &str = "CMD_A_1";

    /// More doc
    pub const CMD_A2: &str = "CMD_A_2";
}

// Actual implementation for A
```

```
// b.rs
pub(super) mod Cmds {
    pub const CMD_B1: &str = "CMD_B_1";
}

// Actual B code
```

```rust
// Base.rs
mod a;
mod b;

mod Cmds {
    pub use super::a::Cmds::*;
    pub use super::b::Cmds::*;   
}
```

This does most of what I want, at least I get my documentation with all the constants listed in a single page.

But additionnal features I'd also like are:

- Having the values of the constant in the list, rather than having to click on each constant and go to its page
- Avoid value collision on the constants (although each submodule will have its own prefix, so its not really an issue)
- Not having to list all the submodules in the `pub use` section
- Maybe avoid the wildcards? I know the reason they are considered bad practice is mainly namespace pollution, which is not an issue when hiding the use in a separate namespace. But I'd rather avoid anything that's seen as bad practice if possible

Is there some crate or macro that does what I want? Or are constants not the way to go? Maybe it's possible for several modules to contribute to the same parent `enum`?

Comment: I would go for [proper enums](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe6172b31e8f244658bbea1bce11f91a) rather than a poor mans enum (`&str`).

Comment: I second @cafce25. Make an enum with `as_str()` method to generate a str on the fly.

Comment: I'm fine with doing that, but it doesn't address my problem of having the full list of variants or consts in a single list, or having to rely on devs thinking about updating the list of re-exports when adding a new submodule.